# Как применить AddConditionalFormat ко всем ячейкам из диапазона(Range)?

Tags: c#, closedxml

Суть проблемы : из кода создаётся xlsx (Excel) документ. В нём есть столбец при определённом значении которого, вся строка должна прокраситься в красный.
В лоб я это решил через цикл, вот так :

```
foreach (var val in new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" })
    worksheet.Cell(val + (i)).AddConditionalFormat().WhenIsTrue("J" + (i) + "=\"НЕ СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ\"").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);
```

Но вероятно же есть способ сделать это без цикла, применив сразу ко всем нужным ячейкам?
Пробовал вот такой вариант :

```
var range = worksheet.Range("A" + (i + 1) + ":J" + (i + 1));
range.AddConditionalFormat().WhenIsTrue("J" + (i + 1) + "=\"НЕ СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ\"").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);
```

Он применяется только к первой ячейки из диапазона. Как его исправить, что бы применилось ко всем?